# How to change gradle metadata location in java builds

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, javac

I have a java project where i am using gradle for build purpose.

I have set GRADLE_USER_HOME to a location where all the artifacts are downloaded and managed, this is working fine and cool.

Inside the project work space there is a .gradle folder generated after the build which has below directories.
1. taskArtifacts --> This has files(fileHashes.bin,fileSnapshots.bin,taskArtifacts.bin and taskArtifacts.lock)
2. tasks

I understand these .gradle folder stores some metadata regarding the project build history. is it possible to move the location of .gradle folder to a external location and use it from there???If so how can i do this?

Comment: Yes, this folder stores metadata specific to a particular build - e.g. task cache. Typically this folder is added to SCM ignore file. Not sure if it can be moved outside, rather not. If so you would need different location for every single build.

Comment: Say for example , Build of the project will be scheduled in different machines every time and cleaned up once build is completed , So i want to keep this .gradle in a centralized location so that new build can utilize metadata. Though i can save this metadata in a location, it would be better to have it in a centralized place.

Comment: I tried copying the metadata to a external location and copying back to a new workspace while building , It didnt pick the old metadata.  --> :compileJava - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I found the way, by passing --project-cache-dir argument we can change the location of local caching.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

Comment: from the docs:  
**--project-cache-dir**  
`Specifies the project-specific cache directory. Default value is .gradle in the root project directory.`